# xcode change label's text after presentViewController

Tags: xcode, label, presentviewcontroller

as always relying on this community wich is always really helpful!

I really don't understand why my code isn't working, i am playing the game in ViewControllerA for example, there is "movements" and more stuff shown,wich are labels with int variables shown, this ones give me no problem because they change correctly,when the game is completed i want to show the score and more...

So i created another ViewController to do it, ViewControllerB for the example, the thing is that A and B Viewcontrollers belong to the SAME class, so i should be able to use the same variables, methods and everything ( actually i do that already and it's working fine)

I created IBOutlet for some labels, this ones belong to B. I am using presentViewcontroller method to show it up,the labels don't get anything changed,  here is the code:

```
NSString *moviments = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",TotalMovements];
NSString *score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",TotalPoints];
NSString *levelToShow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",PlayingLevel];


[movementsToShowOnCompletedScreen setText:moviments];
[scoreToShowOnCompletedScreen setText:score];
[levelToShowOnCompletedScreen setText:levelToShow];

UIStoryboard *winOFLevelStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [winOFLevelStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainGame"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{


    /*I have tried to add the same code from above setting the labels text
    labels here, same result... 

     */
}];
```

The labels don't get its text changed.

This is it, i hope with all of this you can find out what's going on here, the IBOutlets are fine, i even changed programmatically the frame of those labels before so that can't be the problem, outlets are fine.

If you need more code or anyhthing just let me know!

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found it...just in case anyone has the same problem. It solves it but not the way i wanted to so if anyone knows the good way please let me know.

Since those belong to the same class i have just copied/pasted this lines shown below to my viewdidload method, now labels are changing when they have to but i really think this is a really poor solution.

Thanks again!